# symfony 2.8 generated crud controller with errors

Tags: symfony

I try generate CRUD controllers for my entities.

For example I wanna generate CRUD controller for AppBundle\Entity\User\User:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity\User;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\Group;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }
}
```

Generate entities:

```
$ app/console generate:doctrine:entities AppBundle
```

Generate crud:

```
$ app/console doctrine:generate:crud --entity=AppBundle:User\User
```

This command generete follow controller:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Lists all User\User entities.
     *
     * @Route("/", name="user_user_index")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $user\Users = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:User\User')->findAll();

        return $this->render('user/user/index.html.twig', array(
            'user\Users' => $user\Users,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Finds and displays a User\User entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="user_user_show")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function showAction(User $user\User)
    {

        return $this->render('user/user/show.html.twig', array(
            'user\User' => $user\User,
        ));
    }
}
```

What the `$user\Users`? Symfony 2.8!
Maybe I can't use more directories in the Entity folder?

Comment: You should use `AppBundle:User` instead of `AppBundle:User\User`  Also, make sure to check [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/user_manager.html) about FOSUserManagement, since I'm not sure you can manage them with a simple auto-generated CRUD.

Answer (score 1):

if you used the same namespace in your CRUD generation command as you have in this question, I expect that symfony is getting confused.

you have used:

```
AppBundle\Entity\User\User
```

note the extra `\User`.

If this isnt a typo, your entity should reside in the base Entity directory.  The unusual path has probably confused it.

One would have thought however, that the generate command should have validated the string first.

Comment: I should change namespace and move of User class to root entity AppBundle without additional directories?

Comment: put your entity classes in `AppBundle\Entity\`.  Many of the doctrine generate commands dont seem that robust when it comes to validating paths it seems.